# error C2782: 'const _Ty &std::min(const _Ty &,const _Ty &)' : template parameter '_Ty' is ambiguous

Tags: c++, templates

I am building software for 64bit, previously the software built for 32 bit.  The software is completly working for 32bit when I build for 64bit it is giving some error like

```
error C2782: 'const _Ty &std::min(const _Ty &,const _Ty &)' : template parameter '_Ty' is ambiguous
see declaration of 'std::min'
        could be 'size_t'
        or       'unsigned int'
```

for the line

```
unsigned int i = ...;
unsigned int maxPeakWidthInPixel = ...;
size_t steps = ...;
unsigned int endj = min( i + maxPeakWidthInPixel + 1, steps); // error
```

The error is about the compiler not being able to deduce the types of the arguments - but how is this compiling on 32-bit and not 64-bit?

Comment: can we see the code? declaration of variables i, maxPeakWidth and steps

Comment: it means you have mixed types what are `i`, `maxPeakWidthInPixel` and `steps`. The types need to agree in order for the templated code to generate

Comment: What are the types of `maxPeakWidthInPixel` and `steps`?

Comment: I guess it's because `size_t == unsigned int` in 32-bit and `size_t == unsigned long long` in 64-bit.

Comment: So, this error message is caused by the parameter type. But you did not show the declaration of your parameters.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Sorry I forgot to mention the variable declaration. it is "unsigned int ( i + maxPeakWidthInPixel +1), size_t (steps)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the template type explicitly to resolve ambiguity.

```
min<size_t>(...);
```

On the platform you're on `size_t` is not `unsigned int`. So the type deduction mechanism can't know which template instantiation to do.

Alternatively, you can simply avoid mixing types, and perform everything in terms of `size_t` or `unsigned int`. Whichever is preferred for you specific application.

Comment: Thank you, Thats what exactly I needed.

Answer (score 0):

One of the two parameters is a `size_t`, the other one is `unsigned int`. On the 32 bit platform the two are the same type, so there's no issue.

On the 64 bit platform, they are different types, and the `min()` template requires both parameters to have the same type, that's your problem.

Whichever parameter is an `unsigned int`, explicitly cast it to `size_t`. It's probably the first one:

```
unsigned int endj = min( (size_t)(i + maxPeakWidthInPixel + 1), steps);
```

But if it's not, cast the other one to `size_t`, instead.

Comment: Of course the variable `endj` should then also be of type `size_t` (or just `auto`).

Comment: I would say *on your 32 bit platform the two are the same type, so there's no issue.*.  The standard guarantees nothing about size_t except that it is unsigned and that it is *large enough to contain the size
in bytes of any object.*

Comment: Thats worked ! Thank you, I remained endj as unsigned int.

Comment: You could also specify the template type explicitly, and avoid those c-style casts.